# mac osx: using a rsa decryption function of openssl, but it has risk of memory leaks

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-leaks, openssl

I using the openssl rsa function to decrypt the ciphertext, some codes like this:

```
+ (NSString *)RsaDecryptWithPrivateKey:(NSString *)encryptedString {
  void   *encrypt = NULL;    // Encrypted message
  char   *decrypt = NULL;    // Decrypted message
  char   *err = NULL;               // Buffer for any error messages

  BIO *bio = BIO_new_mem_buf((char *)prikey, -1);
  RSA *prikey = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  encrypt = malloc(RSA_size(prikey));

  NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:encryptedString];
  int encryptedData_length = (int)[encryptedData length];
  encrypt = (void *)[encryptedData bytes];

  decrypt = malloc(encryptedData_length);
  memset(decrypt, 0, encryptedData_length);
  if(RSA_private_decrypt(encryptedData_length,
                       (unsigned char*)encrypt,
                       (unsigned char*)decrypt,
                       prikey, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) == -1) {
      ERR_load_crypto_strings();
      ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
      goto free_stuff;        
  }
  return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:decrypt length:strlen(decrypt) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  free_stuff:
    RSA_free(prikey);
    free(encrypt);
    free(decrypt);
    free(err);
}
```

It works fine. However, when I use the Instrument to track leaks about it, there are some warnings shown as follow:
[image]

I do not know how to solve the problem, could you give me some advices?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are `free`ing your allocations after returning from the function unless there is an error (in which case you are not returning anything despite the return type being an `NSString`).

```
NSString *decryptedString = nil;

if(RSA_private_decrypt(encryptedData_length,
                       (unsigned char*)encrypt,
                       (unsigned char*)decrypt,
                       prikey, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) == -1) {
      ERR_load_crypto_strings();
      ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
      goto free_stuff;        
} else {
    decryptedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:decrypt length:strlen(decrypt) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

free_stuff:
  RSA_free(prikey);
  free(encrypt);
  free(decrypt);
  free(err); 

return decryptedString;
```

This way you return `nil` if the decryption failed, but still free everything if the decrypted succeeded.

I haven't actually compiled or tested this so I don't know if that's the problem, but it's something to look at closer at least.

Comment: I modified my codes following your advise, unfortunately, the warnings still occurs.